# c++ dynamic vector creation

Tags: c++, opencv, for-loop

I am using kmeans clustering in opencv, c++. I am trying to create a new vector for each cluster found, and add the resulting points to it.

I have:

```
    vector<cv::Point2f> markerOne;
    vector<cv::Point2f> markerTwo;
    vector<cv::Point2f> markerThree;
    vector<cv::Point2f> markerFour;

Mat labels, centers;

    int  attempts = 50, numberClusters = 4, flags = cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS;
    TermCriteria tc;

    kmeans(centroids, cNumber, labels, tc, attempts, flags, centers);

    for (int i = 0; i < labels.rows; i++)
    {
        int idx = labels.at<int>(i);
        Point2f original_point = centroids[i];
        Point2f clustered_center;
        clustered_center.x = centers.at<float>(idx, 0);
        clustered_center.y = centers.at<float>(idx, 1);
```

What i need from here is to create a vector based on the returned idx value in this loop. I have at the moment:

```
if (idx == 0)
            {
                markerOne.push_back(original_point);                
            }

if (idx == 1)
            {
                markerTwo.push_back(original_point);
            }
if (idx == 2)
            {
            markerThree.push_back(original_point);

          }
if (idx == 3)
          {
            markerFour.push_back(original_point);               
          }
```

There could be up to 100 clusters, so I am looking for a more dynamic way to do this.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a vector-of-vector structure and push the points into the corresponding vector like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Point2f> >  vector_of_vector(labels.rows);
for (int i = 0; i < labels.rows; i++)
{
    vector_of_vector[i].push_back(original_point);

}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I just realised i wasn't specific enough in my question..

updating it now...